# Locally blocking Facebook users blacklist

Tags: facebook, cookies

This is kind of a sensitive matter, I guess, but I'll ask it anyway.

I'm trying to find a way to block a specific list os accounts to access social networking, mainly Facebook - in a boss > employee perspective.

The mostly known answers to this question talk about blocking Facebook itself - but this is not what I need; actually I don't want to block Facebook, as we have a Facebook account for the company and we need the employees to be able to access it.

I've googled it but found no good answers so far.

At first I thought I could monitor the cookies on the system, and scan them for each user from the blacklist. But then again, I found no way to do it, I'm guessing since old Win9x cookies no longer keep track of usernames.

Comment: "facebook account for the company" - if that´s a user profile, then it´s against the terms. only real people (with their real name) are allowed to own user profiles. just a side note. that being said, i don´t see the point of blocking facebook for users - they can just use their smartphone/tablet/whatever and it´s bad for the morale imho. you can always monitor URLs through the company router and check if someone is excessively using FB - after telling everyone that you do it, of course.

Comment: It's not a user profile :) What I mean is I want people to be able to log in facebook but not with their personal accounts. The objective is not to allow them to go play farmville, but to be in touch with customers and followers.

Comment: yeah, i know what you want to achieve, but it´s pretty "conservative" in my opinion. it may or may not be possible to block specific users only, but it´s definitely pointless. people do have smartphones, you know ;)

Comment: btw, are you sure it´s not a user profile? i thought it´s not possible anymore to administer facebook pages without a user profile - so how do you stay in touch with customers and followers? followers are only possible with user profiles anyway...?

Comment: Yes but if they use they spend the time on their phones instead of the counter that will be a problem - see what i mean?
Anyway: I finally got what you mean. Yes. Of course. User profile. Administrator. Of course I can't block it. God damn it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To sum this up from the comments:

You can't block specific FB users through your router, because that would mean that you would need to hack the SSL transfer. The only possibility may be a browser plugin that checks for user logins on facebook.com. For example, you could try to bypass the login button and check the value of the email input field. But i am not sure if that is even allowed, and it is definitely better to just talk to the employees. It should be allowed to check Facebook once in a while imho, as long as it does not harm the work.